# Operator performance in loops

Tags: c, operators

What is quicker in C: operator `!=` or `>`?
I am asking because what if we have a large amount of loops and we have to use one of the above conditions (`while(x!=-1)` or `while(x>0)`).

Also what about other languages.

Comment: What were the results when you tried it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't tried it though I searched it and I didn't find anything constructive.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't make sense to discuss program speed without a specific system in mind.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble so, I was thinking if some binary adds on our most used systems would make a differene in this negotiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most modern processors it will not make any difference.

This is usually compiled as a comparison instruction, which sets certain flags followed by a jump which branches on the combination of some of the flags. There is generally no timing difference between the relational operators.

Some optimizations might omit the branching jumps, but then it is not possible to tell which operator will be more performant, if any. It probably depends on the context.

Of course, if you really want to know for sure, you'll have to do a few test runs and/or profile the code.

Answer (score 1):

hypothetical hardware, version one: (x!=-1)

```
cmp %r1, -1
jeq addr
```

same hypothetical hardware, version two: (x>0)

```
cmp %r1, 0
jle addr
```

unless we know the exact harware, we cant tell, but generally expect them to be same or similar

Either way, I would recommend the version that most clearly express intent.

Comment: Indeed, especially since semantically, `!= -1` is not the same as `> 0`.